# Parse/Heroku and Cocoapods

Tags: swift, heroku, parse-platform, cocoapods, parse-server

I'm very new to iOS developing and recently started working on a project that is a Parse Starter project that is connected to Heroku. With this project, I recently downloaded Cocoapods. I'm a bit confused and was hoping someone can clarify for me.

Every time I work on the project, I have to connect using my terminal to Heroku. Do I have to connect every time I want to use/work on Cocoapods libraries? (I downloaded Stripe via Cocoapods). Or do I only connect to Heroku? I'm a bit confused and hope someone can explain this to me better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**. I will explain.

**Cocoapods**
Cocoapods is dependency manager for iOS (both swift and objective-c projects) and it is relevant only for your iOS client project. 
you need to use Cocoapods each time you add a new dependency to your **podfile**  so for example if you added the line **pod 'Parse'** to your podfile then you need to go to the terminal, navigate to your iOS project and run **pod install** in order to add the parse iOS dependency.

**Heroku**

Heroku is where your you deploy your server side code. Because you use parse-server you can easily deploy it to Heroku and after you deploy it you can access it from your iOS app because the idea of parse server is to expose all the relevant backend functionality for you (e.g. API's, cloud code, push notifications and more) and in your iOS app you can consume those API's via the parse iOS SDK. In order to deploy parse server to heroku you can follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku) guide. If you follow this guide you will need the terminal only to test that your parse-server was deployed successfully to heroku by executing a **curl** request to one of the endpoints that are exposed by parse-server

So to summarise it.

**CocoaPods**  is for your iOS client app and only for it
**Heroku** is the platform where you deploy your parse-server and because parse-server is a **serverless** technology the only thing that you need to do is to configure it for your needs and write some very simple nodejs (usually they are simple :) ) scripts in your cloud code.

If you have more specific questions please let me know.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very helpful!! So next time I go work on the project, I just need to worry about connecting to Heroku on my Terminal like normal? Do I need to add Parse in my pod file? I already deployed my project to Heroku. (Just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you need to add parse to your podfile because it's better to use Parse iOS SDK in order to work against parse-server. about the Heroku you will need to update it only when you updated your cloud code or when a new parse-server version will be released.